# Enviar un Map entre archivos Javascript de html diferentes

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, firebase

Buenas, estoy trabajando con 2 htlm's (**login.html** y **asistencia.html**), cada uno con su respectivo javascript (**login.js** y **asistencia.js**), en login.js creo un map de usuarios (usersMap).

¿Como podria usar **usersMap** en asistencia.js para no tener que crearlo nuevamente?

***login.js***

```
var usersMap = new Map();
var rootRef = firebase.database().ref().child("Users");
rootRef.on("child_added",  function (snap) {
    var userId = snap.child("UserId").val().toString();
    var nameUser = snap.child("Name").val().toString();
    var password= snap.child("Password").val().toString();
    var sede = snap.child("Sede").val().toString();
    var isAdmin = snap.child("IsAdmin").val().toString();

    var newUser = new User(userId, nameUser, password, sede, isAdmin);
    usersMap.set(userId, newUser);
});
```

***asistencia.js***

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var position = location.toString().search("userId");
var userId = location.toString().substring(position);


var marcarBtn = $('#marcarBtn');

marcarBtn.on('click',marcarAsistencia);

function marcarAsistencia(){
    var currentUser = usersMap.get(userId);
}});
```

He intentado poner en asistencia.html lo siguiente, pero no hay resultado.

```
<script src="js/login.js"></script>
<script src="js/asistencia.js"></script>
```

Comment: Que es lo que te trae userMap?, porque si es así, puedes usar una variable global algo así como 
`<script> var mivarialocal; </script>
<script src="js/login.js"></script>
<script src="js/asistencia.js"></script>`

Answer (score 0):

Si son dos páginas distintas creo que no vas a poder directamente porque el contenido se carga a cada petición de la página (incluido los scripts).

Puedes hacer varias cosas:

- Pasar a una aproximación SinglePage usando cualquier framework (angularjs por ejemplo)
- Utilizar algún medio de almacenamiento del navegador (localstorage, sesiones,....), aunque no te lo recomiendo.
- Utilizar un backend, recoger esa información y pasársela a la segunda página.